# Android Studio Gradle Connection refused: connect

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I installed Andorid Studio and the first time I started a new project. 
at compile time I got this error: "Connection refused: connect"

I tried to set proxy and I also tried to use local gradle, but it didn't help.

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication2'.
[...]
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
[...]
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
Required by:
    project :
[...]
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
[...]
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'.
[...]e
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'.
[...]
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to xx.xxx.xx.xx:8080 [/xx.xxx.xx.xx] failed: Connection refused: connect
[...]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[...]
```

Comment: check your internet connection

Comment: I have an internet connection

Comment: use the correct version in destributionUrl in **gradle-wrapper.properties** file.
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip or the above version

Comment: My gradle-wrapper.properties: #Thu Apr 11 11:00:10 CEST 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

Comment: I changed to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4-rc-1-all.zip After downloading i got the same error

Comment: can you show me the project level gradle file . It should have  google() and maven() inside repositories {
        jcenter() google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: inside maven() add url that i have mentioned.

Comment: can you change your gradle version 3.3.1 to 3.3.2 . I have resolved the same issue may be it will help you and then sync the project

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be because of proxy,
As an alternative, download the Gradle distribution and give the path to that zip file in **gradle-wrapper.properties**.

`distributionUrl=../../../tools/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`

Answer (score 0):

it reads:

> Caused by: `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException`:
>
> Connect to xx.xxx.xx.xx:8080 [/xx.xxx.xx.xx] failed: Connection refused: connect

which seems to be a local repository or a local proxy server being at fault.

check the `buildscript` repositories and proxy settings.